# while running mysql_query() getting error working fine in direct phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

while am running the below query using phpmyadmin getting result

```
SET @rownr=0;
SELECT TVGD.video_id,TVM.Video_Title,@rownr:=@rownr+1 AS `Order`,'0' As Min_Pass_Mark
FROM tbl_video_group_details TVGD,tbl_Video_Master TVM WHERE TVGD.video_id=TVM.id AND TVGD.group_id='23'
```

But the same returns syntax error while running using mysql_query() function

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And also make sure that you have added database connection in your file.

Comment: Turn on the **error reporting**, use `mysql_error()` or look into your logfiles! **mysql_*** is marked as **deprecated**, use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: Please show the actual code causing the error (ie, your PHP code). Also add the error message **in full** to your question.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss FYI - error reporting is always *turned on*. Mostly, it is set too low and `display_errors` is disabled

Comment: is group_id field is a string?? if not change TVGD.group_id=23

Comment: @user3091574 Makes no difference. MySQL performs simple type conversion in these cases

Comment: @Phil thats are basics! You not knowing what experiences the questioneer has. And the first step is to get the error messages (few ways for that).

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I just figured OP would look for `error_reporting` based on your comment, see that it has a value (probably `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`) and leave it at that. Better advice would be to set `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in `php.ini` and restart the web server.

Comment: @Phil yes, but on productive systems is `display_errors` bad. Okay, for a little test,... but the best way is to look ito the logfiles, additional set a Logfile for that (`error_log` & `log_errors`, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I should have added *"... on your local development machine"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_query()` does not support multiple statements like 1) `SET @rownr=0;` 2) your query for this you can rewrite your query as below

```
SELECT 
  TVGD.video_id,
  TVM.Video_Title,
  @rownr := @rownr + 1 AS `Order`,
  '0' AS Min_Pass_Mark 
FROM
  tbl_video_group_details TVGD,
  tbl_Video_Master TVM ,
  (SELECT @rownr := 0) t
WHERE TVGD.video_id = TVM.id 
  AND TVGD.group_id = '23'
```

or you can use [*mysqli::multi_query*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) which does support multiple statements